# Unable to start Solr with G1GC

Tags: java, solr, g1gc

I am using Solr 7.7

I am trying to start my solr server with G1 GC instead of the default CMS but the solr service doesn't get up.

The command I use to start solr is

```
bin/solr start -p 8000 -a "-Dsolr.solr.home=<solrhomepath> -Denable.slave=true -Denable.master=false -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1NewSizePercent=5 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70"
```

I have tried various permutations of the start command by dropping / adding other parameters but it doesn't work. However starts up just fine with just

```
"-Dsolr.solr.home=<solrhomepath> -Denable.slave=true -Denable.master=false"
```

and starts up with the default CMS collector

I don't get any useful error logs too. It waits for default 180 secs and then prints

```
Warning: Available entropy is low. As a result, use of the UUIDField, SSL, or any other features that require
RNG might not work properly. To check for the amount of available entropy, use 'cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail'.

Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 25280 [|]  Still not seeing Solr listening on 25280 after 180 seconds!
2020-07-15 07:07:52.042 INFO  (coreCloseExecutor-60-thread-6) [   x:coreName] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [coreName]  CLOSING SolrCore org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore@7cc638d8
2020-07-15 07:07:52.099 INFO  (coreCloseExecutor-60-thread-6) [   x:coreName] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for registry=solr.core.coreName, tag=7cc638d8
2020-07-15 07:07:52.100 INFO  (coreCloseExecutor-60-thread-6) [   x:coreName] o.a.s.m.r.SolrJmxReporter Closing reporter [org.apache.solr.metrics.reporters.SolrJmxReporter@5216981f: rootName = null, domain = solr.core.coreName, service url = null, agent id = null] for registry solr.core.coreName / com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry@32988ddf
2020-07-15 07:07:52.173 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for registry=solr.node, tag=null
2020-07-15 07:07:52.173 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ] o.a.s.m.r.SolrJmxReporter Closing reporter [org.apache.solr.metrics.reporters.SolrJmxReporter@28952dea: rootName = null, domain = solr.node, service url = null, agent id = null] for registry solr.node / com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry@655f4a3f
2020-07-15 07:07:52.175 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for registry=solr.jvm, tag=null
2020-07-15 07:07:52.175 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ] o.a.s.m.r.SolrJmxReporter Closing reporter [org.apache.solr.metrics.reporters.SolrJmxReporter@69c6161d: rootName = null, domain = solr.jvm, service url = null, agent id = null] for registry solr.jvm / com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry@1252ce77
2020-07-15 07:07:52.176 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ] o.a.s.m.SolrMetricManager Closing metric reporters for registry=solr.jetty, tag=null
2020-07-15 07:07:52.176 INFO  (ShutdownMonitor) [   ] o.a.s.m.r.SolrJmxReporter Closing reporter [org.apache.solr.metrics.reporters.SolrJmxReporter@3aefae67: rootName = null, domain = solr.jetty, service url = null, agent id = null] for registry solr.jetty / com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry@3a538ecd
```

Comment: Give the `-f` parameter - that should start Solr in the foreground and give you all the output from the server process directly.

Comment: thanks. that shows an error "Conflicting collector combinations in option list; please refer to the release notes for the combinations allowed". Will debug now.

Comment: Check `solr.in.sh` for the default values given when starting Solr. My guess is that there's a different GC specified as the default there.